# Meteor Facebook login (Meteor.loginWithFacebook) issue extracting public profile, email and user_friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor, meteor-accounts

Trying to get Meteor Facebook login to work. It functions fully in that it uses Facebook API and requests the correct permissions from the users account and then logs in successfully.

The problem is it doesn't save the permission requested information even though its been approved and only the basic name and ID are available in Meteor.user().services.facebook. Is this code not working because it's not saving the users details on login? I can't find a resource that details how to save or extract the other data.

Simply trying to console log the data to see that it's been extracted out of the Facebook user account on log in.

Within Meteor.isClient code:

```
Template.login.events({
'click #facebook-login': function(event) {
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook({ requestPermissions: ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends', 'user_likes']}, function(err){
        if (err) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("Facebook login failed");
        }
        console.log(Meteor.user().services.facebook.name);
        console.log(Meteor.user().services.facebook.id);
        console.log(Meteor.user().services.facebook.email);
        console.log(Meteor.user().services.facebook.gender);            
    });
},

'click #logout': function(event) {
    Meteor.logout(function(err){
        if (err) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("Logout failed");
        }
    });
}
```

The config code:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
    service: 'facebook'
});

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: 'facebook',
    appId: 'correctAppID',
    secret: 'CorrectSecret'
});
```

Comment: Probably the problem that been discussed a lot lately, that API v2.4 doesn’t return all fields by default any more, but the fields one wants must be specifically requested. Go ask the people providing the library, if they adapted their code to that change already.

Comment: That would explain why none of the other git hub code and forum posts have been helping. I'll have a look at the changes in more detail and update what I work out from it. Thanks

Comment: You’ll find the relevant change here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes, section titled “Declarative Fields”. I’d assume that Meteor makes a request for `/me` somewhere to request the user profile, but that would now have to be written as `/me?fields=email,gender,every-other-field-youre-interested-in`. Since you’re not making that call yourself in the code shown, I’d think it is probably “hidden“ somewhere in the script internals. They’ll have to update that, for it to work the same way as before.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will close the question as answered once I get it working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Facebook v2.4 API after you have requested for certain permissions you can then access them by making a graph API call and requesting them with a valid auth token. The code is as follows:

```
if (user.hasOwnProperty('services') && user.services.hasOwnProperty('facebook')  ) {
        var result = Meteor.http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/' + user.services.facebook.id + '?access_token=' + user.services.facebook.accessToken + '&fields=first_name, last_name, birthday, email, gender, location, link, friends');

        console.log(result.data.first_name);
        console.log(result.data.last_name);
        console.log(result.data.birthday);
        console.log(result.data.email);
        console.log(result.data.gender);
        console.log(result.data.location);
        console.log(result.data.link);
        console.log(result.data.friends);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I think I am having a similar issue here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244778/cannot-see-extra-facebook-permissions-in-created-user-in-meteor/32244959?noredirect=1#comment52373162_32244959) Could you help me figure out how to go about getting the extra permissions if I'm using loginButtons. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution helped be, but I never receive birthday or location in the result. Is this something normal?