# Cannot see extra Facebook permissions in created user in Meteor

Tags: facebook, meteor, permissions

I am developing an App with Meteor and asking for extra permissions from Facebook with the following code...

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    facebook: ['user_likes', 'user_education_history', 'user_hometown', 'user_location', 'user_website', 'user_work_history']
  },
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_OPTIONAL_EMAIL'
});
```

I as an Admin is allowing for those permissions to be published but when the user is created, these permissions do not get added to the Meteor.user.

Is there something extra I need to do to add them to the DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user)

> On the client, this will be the subset of the fields in the document that are published from the server (other fields won't be available on the client). By default the server publishes username, emails, and profile (writable by user). See Meteor.users for more on the fields used in user documents.

Meaning you need to create publish to return extra fields to client

Comment: I actually have auto-publish on at the moment, so everything should be published by default. And even when I use Terminal to look into db.user.find() I do not see those extra Facebook permissions in there. All I see are the public-profile fields.

Comment: And when you login via Facebook you can see all those permissions listed when its asking for them?

Comment: Yes, the permissions are being allowed by my profile to the App. But they don't show up in my User Collection.

Comment: And you're using loginButtons or Meteor.loginWithFacebook~ ?

Comment: I'm using loginButtons. I was using Meteor.loginWithFacebook earlier but that broke when I deployed the App.

Comment: According to http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice loginWithFacebook also accepts requestPermissions field, maybe try to override it or give loginWithFacebook another try

Comment: Did all that following the Docs. No luck. I came here after exhausting all other options. The App asks for permissions while Logging In. The permissions are granted but nothing shows up.

Comment: No idea then, there must be some other part of code causing this problem. If you are sure you did everything right, file an issue on GitHub