# Cannot access additional Facebook Permissions in Meteor

Tags: jquery, facebook, meteor

need a little help here ... I am try to access from Facebook a little more than public_profile and email with the following code ...

```
'click #facebook-login': function(event) {
var permissions = ['email', 'user_education_history', 'user_location', 'user_website', 'user_work_history'];
            Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
                requestPermissions : permissions
                }, function(err){
                    if (err) 
                        throw new Meteor.Error("Facebook login failed");
                    if(Meteor.user().firstLogin) {
                        Router.go('/fbRegister');
                    }
            });
        },
```

The permission are asked for when I click the Login button and as an Admin I allow these permissions and I double checked on Facebook that the permissions are allowed. But they do not show up in the Meteor.user(). 
How can access these additional permissions??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you publishing the keys used for the fb permissions on the server and subscribing to that publication on the client? By default only the *emails* and *profile* keys of the user object are sent to the client.

Comment: Yes I am. And even it I use the Terminal for db.users.find(), all I see are the email and profile. Rest of the permissions just aren't there.

Comment: Sorry, your question was about accessing the fb permissions, not saving them. It appears that your question is a dupe of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615540/meteor-facebook-login-meteor-loginwithfacebook-issue-extracting-public-profile) which you have already seen. It appears the permissions are not actually stored in Meteor.user() but are available via the fb graph api. This is probably to make sure they are always up-to-date since the user can revoke anyone of them at any time.

Comment: Thanks for that. Even though you didn't exactly answer the question, you did help me figure it out. I had seen the other question before but I couldn't make it work. I was making all the calls on Client side. Thanks :)